# How to design a one time use page

Tags: mobile, user-behavior, user-expectation

I have a web page where a user will perform some sort of 'unlock' action to show that they've won something. However, this page needs to be only unlockable once (i.e. it's lost if they navigate elsewhere or close the tab). I have tried searching around for some examples, but I can't find anything. One of my big concerns is users prematurely 'unlocking' their prize (which is redeemed physically) before they can physically redeem it, then lose the redemption screen and be sad. How can I make it super clear in my UI that you can only click a button, once, forever, and if it goes away on their phone, it's gone?

Comment: Do you plan to tell them how they need to "physically redeem it" before they unlock their prize?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles yeah

Comment: Just use text and say that after click this page is gone.

Answer (score 3):

Start with the "Unlock" button disabled and make your list of requirements a checklist, and after every item on the list is checked enable the "Unlock" button.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxMGqy.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the major things is that you'll want to prevent accidental clicks. Next to making clear this is a one time thing.

I'm instantly thinking about a button you have to press for a longer amount of time to activate it.

Next to textual cues about the conditions, you can enhance the precarious, final nature of the offer by adding animations.
Let it go up in smoke or explode. That pretty final.
An easy implementation of this I can think of quickly is the 'hinge' animation in [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/).

Hope this helps.